# How to negate angular pattern/regex

Tags: regex

I have the following code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvxifq-qrjtpg

```
pattern="^\s+$"
```

I need to negate this, because as of now I got error when I put a letter, but it should only show error IF there is only white space.

I tried using `?!` but it shows an error

Comment: It should not accept only spaces right?

Comment: empty or only space should return the error. 
If I write anything like 100space and a letter, this should be ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(?: *[^\s] *)+$
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/th0A3A/3/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a negative lookahead `(?!`, you could check if from the start till the end of the string there are no whitespace characters:

```
pattern="^(?!\s*$)[\s\S]+$"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4l3edZ/1)

That will match

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!\s*$)` Negative lookahead, assert that what follows is not 0+ whitespace characters and end of string
- `[\s\S]+` Match 1+ times any character including new lines
- `$` End of string